# what does this warning mean: Expect list<fields_enum>; got <class 'list'>

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-insights

I'm running a python programm to fetch facebook insights metrics.
I get this warning:

*UserWarning: value of fields might not be compatible.  Expect list<fields_enum>;  got <class 'list'>*

And this is (a part of) my code:

```
 FIELDS          = [
                     (adsinsights.AdsInsights.Field.ad_id),
                     (adsinsights.AdsInsights.Field.adset_name),        
                     (adsinsights.AdsInsights.Field.campaign_id),  

                     (adsinsights.AdsInsights.Field.reach),
                     (adsinsights.AdsInsights.Field.frequency),
                     (adsinsights.AdsInsights.Field.impressions),
                     (adsinsights.AdsInsights.Field.spend),

                     (adsinsights.AdsInsights.Field.inline_link_clicks),
                     (adsinsights.AdsInsights.Field.unique_clicks),

                     (adsinsights.AdsInsights.Field.cost_per_inline_link_click),
                     (adsinsights.AdsInsights.Field.cost_per_inline_post_engagement),
                     (adsinsights.AdsInsights.Field.cost_per_unique_click)
                   ]

 def readInsightsFromCampaign(campaignId):
     FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN, api_version=API_VERSION)

     c = campaign.Campaign(campaignId)
     params = {
         'level': adsinsights.AdsInsights.Level.account,
         'date_preset': campaign.Campaign.DatePreset.last_90d,
         'fields': FIELDS
     }

     insights = c.get_insights(params=params)
     return insights
```

What does this warning mean? And how can I avoid it?

Many thanks,
Tim

Comment: I get the same warning, do you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this would help you a lot : https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk/blob/master/README.md